# praw: get domain listings error

Tags: python, reddit, praw

In praw, I want to iterate over some domains and get their newest submissions

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit("test")
r.login(username=uname, password=pass)

domains = ['example.com', 'google.com']

for domain in domains:
    recents = r.get_domain_listing(domain, sort='new',limit=3)
    for res in recent:
        print res.title
```

This code (with a different domain list) raises `AttributeError: '<class 'praw.objects.Submission'>' has no attribute 'get_domain_listing'`  after printing out results for the first domain

Can someone help me out with this? [docs for get_domain_listing](http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.__init__.UnauthenticatedReddit.get_domain_listing)

Answer (score 0):

> This code (with a different domain list) raises `AttributeError: '<class 'praw.objects.Submission'>' has no attribute 'get_domain_listing'` after printing out results for the first domain

Is the code posted the exact code used? Based on that quoted line, it seems like you might be doing something like `for r in recent`, which would overwrite the global `r` object with a `Submission` object instead of the `Reddit` object it was initialized to at the top of your code.